# nodejs child_process.spawn msdeploy.exe with space in dest site

Tags: node.js, space, child-process, spawn

I am trying to use `child_process.spawn` with msdeploy.exe to automate deployement of some applications in IIS.

Whenever i have a space in my dest site name this makes msdeploy crash.

```
var command = 'C:/Program Files/IIS/Microsoft Web Deploy V3/msdeploy.exe';
var args = [];
args.push('-verb=sync');
args.push('-source:iisApp=C:/Users/PATH_TO_DEPLOY/dist');
args.push('-dest:iisApp=Default Web Site/test');

var process = spawn(command,args);

process.stdout.on('data', function(data) { grunt.log.write(data) });
process.stderr.on('data', function(data) { grunt.log.error(data); });
process.on('exit', function(code) {
    if (code !== 0) {
        grunt.fail.warn('Something went wrong');
    }
    done();
});
```

I've tried some others alternative like put " `'-dest:iisApp="Default Web Site/test"'` but msdeploy give me an error too.
This error is like : `Argument '"-dest:iisApp=Default Web Site/haha"' not recognized. All arguments must begin with "-" char`.

When i try to escape the space char or put " like describe above this gave me a similar error.

Is this is a bug in nodejs ? Maybe i've made something wrong ?
Thank.

Answer (score 0):

How to accomplish this:

```
var path = require('path');
var platform = require('platform');
var cp = require('child_process');

var full_cmd = '/path/to/dir with space/program.exe';
var cmd = '.' + path.sep + path.basename(full_cmd); // cannot include double quotes -- the work-around is to use the 'cmd_opts.cwd'
var cmd_args = ['"--import-path=/path/to/dir with space/import_file"']; // can wrap each with double-quotes (Windows only -- fails on Unix)
var cmd_opts = {
    cwd: path.dirname(full_cmd),
    encoding: 'utf8'
};
if (platform.os() === 'win32') {
    cmd_opts.windowsVerbatimArguments = true;
}
var proc = cp.spawn(
    cmd,
    cmd_args,
    cmd_opts
);
```

The only way this doesn't work is if 'program.exe' is named something like 'program name with space.exe'